# twitter bootstrap: why only badge(label)-inverse works on <a> tag?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, label, badge

I want to use badge (or label) on my links (elements). but only badge-inverse works and the black badge shows. other badges or labels all are displayed in Default color. 
I don't want to use  inside my  element.

any solutions?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your css-addon file. One of your Css declaration is probably overriding `badge` and `label classes`. When I only use Bootstrap CSS, that works perfectly !

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandreT/uzD5v/1/

Comment: you were right. I have used one of the samples of Bootswatch and apparently it has made some changes which affects it. It worked when I used pure Bootstrap CSS files. I should figure it out how to solve it. Just a quick hint. should I go into css file or should I change .less file? Thank you.

Comment: You should go into **your** css file, not Bootstrap css or less file. Go to my JSFIDDLE, fork it, in the upper right add your Css content. So we can have a look to your matter. When done give us your link.

Comment: I got rid of Bootswatch. the only benefit it had was the color of its navbar which I created it myself. thank you so much.